# Object not initialized with autowire

Tags: spring

I use spring boot 3

I created a object manually, FormGenerator, because everytime I use is in my advance search, some field need to be reset.

So I think the scope prototype is ok for that

```
@Repository
public class SchoolRepositoryCustomImpl  extends SimpleJpaRepository<School, Long> implements SchoolRepositoryCustom  {


    @Override
    public List<School> advanceSearch(SchoolSearch search) {
        FormGenerator qg = new FormGenerator();

    }

    ...

}
@Scope("prototype")
public class FormGenerator {

    private int fieldCounter=0;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    ...
}
```

When I run application, entityManager is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `null` because you created the object manually by calling the constructor. You need to obtain it from the `ApplicationContext`. Something like this:

```java
@Repository
public class SchoolRepositoryCustomImpl  extends SimpleJpaRepository<School, Long> implements SchoolRepositoryCustom  {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;    

    @Override
    public List<School> advanceSearch(SchoolSearch search) {
        FormGenerator qg = applicationContext.getBean(FormGenerator.class);

    }

    ...

}
```